# Constructing an SQL Query to retrieve field goal percentage of all teams

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by, sum

Consider the SQL "Players" table below

[image]

What sort of SQL query could I write to calculate the field goal percentage of each team?

A field goal percentage is calculated as fgm / fga.

Edit:
What I've tried thus far is, `SELECT Team, fga / fgm as fgp FROM Players` but that only gives me the percentage for each individual player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your current query:

```
SELECT team, fgm / fga as fgp FROM Players as a
```

You can just turn on aggregation with `group by team` and divide the sum of made field goals by the sum of attempts:

```
SELECT team, SUM(fgm) / SUM(fga) as fgp FROM Players as a GROUP BY team
```

Some databases do integer division. So if your numbers are stored as integers, and you want a decimal result:

```
SELECT team, 1.0 * SUM(fgm) / SUM(fga) as fgp FROM Players as a GROUP BY team
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with me, I wasn't aware you could just perform calculations like that right inline.